# Selenium send_keys and clear no longer work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When trying to run this code to input a certain string into the search box, Python returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear' and it does the same with send_keys as well. I have another python file opened that works fine when running and is a able to send keys and clear items. Also when doing shift-tab to find the description of what send_keys and clear does, it does not say anything.

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'C:\webdriver.exe\chromedriver.exe',port=9515)

url = 'https://www.dividend.com'

chrome.get(url)

main_page = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("t-cursor-pointer.nav-full-screen-search").click()
time.sleep(2)

search_bar = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("twitter-typeahead").click().send_keys()

time.sleep(2)

search_bar.send_keys("XOM")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'C:\webdriver.exe\chromedriver.exe',port=9515)

url = 'https://www.dividend.com'

chrome.get(url)

main_page = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("t-cursor-pointer.nav-full-screen-search")
main_page.click()
time.sleep(2)

search_bar = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("twitter-typeahead")
search_bar.click()
search_bar.clear()

time.sleep(2)

search_bar.send_keys("XOM")
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried this and it still does not work. For a moment it displayed that send_keys and clear were recognized functions then python no longer was able to display what they did when I pressed shift-tab, and it still giver me the NoneType Error

Comment: Then you might have an error with the elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For `search_bar`, actually you need `input`, instead of this `span`:

```
search_bar = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("twitter-typeahead")
```

And instead of `time.sleep(...)` please use `WebDriverWait`.

Try following code:

```
url = 'https://www.dividend.com'
chrome.get(url)
search_icon = WebDriverWait(chrome, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'nav a.t-cursor-pointer.nav-full-screen-search')))
search_icon.click()

search_bar = WebDriverWait(chrome, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.twitter-typeahead input')))
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys('XOM')
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```